# convention for non-commutative multiplication tables

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, convention

Is there a standard convention for multiplication tables for non-commutative multiplication? Should the first multiplicand be the rows or columns?

That is, if we have

| * | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | b |
| b | a | b |

then is $ab = b$ or $a$?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a convention. I would read $ab$ as specifying the row and then the column. In any case be sure to tell your reader what your convention is.

Comment: Like Ethan, I always assume the row furnishes the left hand thing in the product, and the column furnishes the right.